# Create a WebPage with table from data

Tags: html-table, frameworks

**What are simple solutions for creating a web-page (or only the HTML-Table) from data?**

We have a web-service which returns the data.
This data is put in an HTML table - all manual via simple JavaScript.

Unfortunately this open question does not lead to any good results on google ..
I remember [D3js](https://d3js.org/) which visualizes data.
But I would like to compare a few frameworks..

What do you use and like best ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several frameworks and libraries available that can simplify the process of creating HTML tables from data.

1.DataTables

2.Tabulator

3.Handsontable

4.Ag-Grid